# Ubuntu 16.04.1 won't suspend (Laptop)

Tags: suspend

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.1 on my Lenovo Twist and having issues suspending. Every once in a while it will work 'normally' but on occasion, it will immediately wake when I try to suspend. I did upgrade the kernal to 4.4.8 because i was having issues with freezes on wake. Anyone else having similar issues? Any ideas of how to fix it? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, happens to many users here. When it happens on my system, there is always a failed suspend job. (System places it there blocking the kernel suspend while services are closed down safely.  Some service is not cooperating, so the suspend job stays in the way).

When it happens, open a terminal and run

```
$ ps aux | grep suspend
```

You'll see 2 lines, one caused by the grep and the other is the failed suspend from your effort.  There are many threads about this, but so far as I have found, only "fix" is to kill the suspend job, as in

```
$ sudo kill -9 nnnnn
```

where nnnnn is the job number that shows in the ps aux output.

Be aware your system will suspend immediately, as soon as you hit return.

The first few times this happened to me, I was very caution to reboot completely to make sure all of the services were restarted correctly. I think that's the right thing to do. Sometimes I've been in a hurry and I did not restart and the only problem seems to be the network devices don't wake up.